# A question about recursive programming in python

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to implement a recursive function in python, let's call such function `F`, the input of such function is a list, lets call it `a`. The logic of the realization of `F` should be as following,

```
def F(a):
    if this is first time I run this function (in other words if this is not the first time I run this function, leave a as it is):
        a.reverse()
    then do something recursively calling F
```

I want to ask that what is the simplest way of achieving such goal. Does python actually support such logic?

Comment: You either make a wrapper function to call `F` and do what you need to first or something like `F(a, first_time=False)` and call it via `F(a, True)`

Comment: @Sayse Wrapper solution is cleaner, it avoids having to evaluate `first_time` in every recursive call.  Wrappers are a good solution to one-time setup issues or data cleaning such as bounds checks.

Comment: Hi, thx for your comment. I don't want any extra variable in the function. So can you elaborate on what you mean by wrapper function in this case?

Comment: You make `def Fx()` that calls `F` after doing whatever presetup you need

Comment: @pjs - Yes it is assuming you're in a position where you're able to refactor easily to introduce a wrapper function, the latter is for times when thats not the case

Comment: @Sayse I'd name it the other way 'round though.  The wrapper is the public-facing interface, the recursion handles things behind the scenes.

Comment: You can always make F() wrapper for a new function, that way there is no change visible outside thus no need for a refactor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, you make `F` a wrapper around a separate recursive helper function.

```
def F(a):
    def helper(a):
        "Do recursive stuff"

    a.reverse()
    return helper(a)
```

If, for whatever reason, it is prohibitively expensive to re-define `_F_helper` each time `F` is called, you can define it outside `F`:

```
def _F_helper(a):
    "Do recursive stuff"

def F(a):
    a.reverse()
    return _F_helper(a)
```

The benefit of either approach is that you don't spend a lot of time trying to decide whether or not `a.reverse()` should be called. It gets called unconditionally *once*, and *then* you proceed with the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
def F(a):
    F.counter += 1
    print(F.counter)
    if F.counter == 1:
       a.reverse() 
    F(a)
F.counter = 0
F(a)
```

you no need to define a global variable or any other

Comment: This looks very expensive compared to using a simple wrapper.

Comment: Very unfortunate, this method doesn't seem to work. ```currentframe```doesn't accept any input.

Comment: @CoolGas sorry for that i changed my approach . try this will works this is not expensive compared to other

Answer (score -1):

you can input root into your function:

```
def F(a:list,radical = 0):
    old_a = a.copy()
    if radical == 0:
        a.reverse()
    # do sometihing ......
    return F(old_a,radical + 1)
```

Comment: Can potentially be a solution, but I don't want any extra variable in the function.